# code push rollback always

Tags: cordova, code-push

i open project cordova in vs 2015 and install plugin code push, I copied a project that was found in folder "plugin code push" and I succeeded push, but if close my aplication it is rollback, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems: 
a)  I'm using cordova and if the release command is general and not release-cordova command in next resume your ape have rollback. 
b) I did not see all doc for code-push and written there  "If you are manually checking ... method notifyApplicationReady() must be called", if is dont called server think your program crash and pley rollback before save you.
c) i copy index.js have in code-push directory (advenced) and is crash my program and if program crash is give rollback, I checked And I found onConfirm function crashed program i dont now why, i delete this function and its work.